# Line integral problem

Tags: integration

Could anyone please show me the error of my ways! I disagree with the answer in the back of the text book I'm working from.

**Question:**

Evaluate the line integral:

$I=\oint\limits_c\frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2+4}$

where c is the boundary of the segment formed by the arc of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ and the chord $y=2-x$ for $x \geqslant0$

**Book answer** is $\frac{\pi}{24}(3-4\sqrt2)\approx-0.34778$

**My answer:**

Here's a plot to help visualize:

[http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/function-grapher.php?func1=sqrt(4-x^2)&func2=2-x&xmin=-5.000&xmax=5.000&ymin=-3.091&ymax=3.091](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/function-grapher.php?func1=sqrt(4-x%5E2)&func2=2-x&xmin=-5.000&xmax=5.000&ymin=-3.091&ymax=3.091)

The curves intersect at A(2,0) and B(0,2) so break the integral into two pieces $I_1$ and $I_2$

**$I_1=$ From A to B on the circle**

Here $x^2+y^2=4 \therefore$

$y = \sqrt{4-x^2}=(4-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\therefore$

$dy = \frac{1}{2}(4-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\times-2xdx=$

$\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \therefore$

$I_1=\int_2^0\frac{x}{8}\times-\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{8}dx=\frac{1}{8}\int_2^0-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$

**$I_2=$ From B to A on the straight line**

here $y=2-x \therefore dy=-dx$ and $y^2=(2-x)^2=4-4x+x^2\therefore$

$x^2+y^2+4=2x^2-4x+8\therefore$

$I_2=\int_0^2\frac{-x-(2-x)}{2x^2-4x+8}dx=-\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^2-2x+4}dx$

ok, at this point I put the integrals into Wolfram Alpha and sum them to see if I'm right so far and I get:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+[%281%2F8%29*%28-x^2%2Fsqrt%284-x^2%29-sqrt%284-x^2%29%29]+between+2+and+0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+[%281%2F8%29*%28-x%5E2%2Fsqrt%284-x%5E2%29-sqrt%284-x%5E2%29%29]+between+2+and+0)

and

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+[-1%2F%28x^2-2x%2B4%29]+between+0+and+2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+[-1%2F%28x%5E2-2x%2B4%29]+between+0+and+2)

and these sum to 0.1808 which is not the books answer. I've doubtless made a mistake, can anyone put me right?

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: Your solution seems right!